# how to export kendo-chart to pdf

Tags: kendo-chart

am using kendo data vizualization api to render dashboard page with charts

user does some selection on page which triggers ajax call and draws the charts on this dashboard page.

i need to add the feature to export the dashboard page with multiple charts to pdf

i tried phantom js but am not clear how to make it work in this context where current user is already logged in and on dashbaord page and clicks on export to pdf button.

my web layer is using asp.net 3.5 and i dont want to mix the mvc.dll solution as posted on kendo site in my project.

has any one tried this before ? please hlp.

thanks.

Comment: in the recent release kendo added these features to their controls [method 1](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/chart-api/export)                 [method 2](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/drawing/export)

Answer (score 1):

This JS code exports all rendered to container element with ID 'your_container_with_charts_inside' charts to PDF:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    var $element = $('#your_container_with_charts_inside');

    kendo.drawing.drawDOM($element)
    .then(function (group) {
        return kendo.drawing.exportPDF(group, {
            paperSize: "auto",
            margin: { left: "1cm", top: "1cm", right: "1cm", bottom: "1cm" }
        });
    })
    .done(function (data) {
        kendo.saveAs({
            dataURI: data,
            fileName: "export.pdf",
        });
    });

});
```

Also you might want to check [Chart API / PDF Export demo](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/chart-api/pdf-export)